# grep pattern next two lines and discard the pattern with one line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I have a file something like this:

dn: danan

cn: danian

cn: danian1

---

dn: danian2

cn: danian2

---

dn: danian3

cn: danian3

cn: danian4

all I want to do is grep the pattern "dn:" and print just the next 2 lines, but when I run grep -A 2 "dn:" the result is everything in the file, I just want to print the next 2 lines not the next 1 line

Comment: What do you mean with "he result is everything in the file, I just want to print the next 2 lines not the next 1 line,"? `grep -A 2` should print the next 2 lines after each match.

Comment: I mean , when  I run grep -A 2 "dn:" the output is the next 2 lines and the next 1 line i just want to print the 2 next lines

Comment: root@danian:~# cat dare | grep -A 2 "dn:" 
dn: cn=danian@gmial.com
cn: danian+@hotmail.com
cn: danian2B@hotmail.com
--
dn: daniandare1@hotmail.com
cn: danian1@gf.es --> discard this line becouse is just 1 next line

dn: daniandare2@hotmail.com
cn: danian2@gf.es --> discard this line becouse is just 1 next line


dn: danianlnx@hotmail.com
cn: dana@gmail.com
cn: fggh@dare.es

Comment: Do you mean you *don't* want to see "danian2" from the example, because it has only one line of "cn" text following it, instead of the two lines that the others have?

Comment: exactly, the output is both 2 lines and one,, I just want to print just the next 2 lines and discard the next one line

Comment: I think you need to put the desired output into the question where it can be legibly formatted instead of as a comment. Also, please read up on how to format a section as `code` in the question.

Comment: Is that a typo in the first line? Should it be `dn: danian`? If the desired output is what I'm thinking, there's a much easier way to do it. Add what you want to your question so that there is a better idea of what you want.

Comment: You have 3 lines starting with "dn:", and each of those lines is followed by either 1 or 2 lines that start with "cn:". Since `grep -A 2 "dn:"` returns all the lines that start with "dn:" and the next two lines following each of them, that means all the lines are returned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I run the command above and works perfectly,

```
awk -v RS="\n\n" -v FS="\n" -v ORS="\n\n" 'NF>2 {print $0}'
```

the blocks delimited are blanck, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
$ awk -v RS="dn: " -v FS="\n" -v ORS="" 'NF>3 {print "dn:",$0}' input.txt
```

We define `dn:` as a record separator. The fields in one record are delimited by a new line character `\n`.

In case you have two lines following a line starting with `dn:`, before a new record starts with `dn:`, you will have 3 times a "\n" leading to 4 fields in the record. This is why we check if there are more than 3 fields in the record (`NF>3`). If that is the case, we print out the whole record, but need to prepend the `dn:`.

Note that `NF>3` will find all records with more than two following lines in one record. If you want only those with exact two change it to `NF==3`.

If the blocks are delimited by a blank line (as it seems in one of your later comments) use this instead:

```
$ awk -v RS="\n\n" -v FS="\n" -v ORS="\n\n" 'NF>2 {print $0}' input.txt
```

Comment: Instead of piping to `grep`, you could pass in `-v ORS=""`.

Comment: Very good. I've edited my answer.